# removing elements from an array list

Tags: java, arraylist

consider I have an array list like : `[2,5,1,8,6]`
and I want to remove all elements from `1` till the end .and the arraylist will be like :`[2,5]`
how can i do this?
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is worth noting that you cannot add/remove from an Arrays.asList(), but you can do.

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(2, 5, 1, 8, 6);
int idx = list.indexOf(1);
if (idx>=0) list = list.subList(0, idx);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(2, 5, 1, 8, 6);
boolean remove = false;
Iterator<Integer> it = list.iterator();
while (it.hasNext() {
   if (!remove && it.next() == 1) {
      remove = true;
   }
   if (remove) {
      it.remove();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list = list.subList(0, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

**The most efficient way to remove elements from ArrayList is to remove them from the end of the list.** Each element you remove from the middle of the list will result in all the latter elements being [moved to the left](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove%28int%29). If the list is large, this can result in a significant performance issue.

However, in your case, you might be better off just creating a new [sublist](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html#subList%28int,%20int%29) with the remaining two elements.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it would be to simply pop items off the end of the `List` until we have popped the starting element. Each item can be popped in O(1) time, so the entire operation is O(n).

```
class Main{
    private static List<Integer> inputs = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public static void main(String args[]){
        for (int x: new int[]{2,5,1,8,6})
            inputs.add(x);
        System.out.println(inputs);
        int start=inputs.indexOf(1);
        if (start>=0){ //check if there is a 1 in input
            while (inputs.size()>start)
                inputs.remove(inputs.size()-1);
        }
        System.out.println(inputs);

    }
}
```